# Add string to list by analyzing list item value (agregar string a lista if item=='valor' )

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

necesito agregar un string en una lista, con un valor dependiendo del valor de un atributo de la lista

---

I need to add a string in a list, with a value depending on the value of an attribute in the list

```yml
#ambprueba.yml

LIST_BASES: 
  - { BASE: 'ambprueba_sc',TWO_TASK: 'sc' }
  - { BASE: 'ambprueba_si',TWO_TASK: 'si' }        
  - { BASE: 'ambprueba_slucs',TWO_TASK: '001' }
  - { BASE: 'ambprueba_sluod',TWO_TASK: '105' }
```

## --------------------------

```
#Ambiente=ambprueba (in this case)

  - name: "Include vars in {{ Ambiente }}.yml"
    include_vars:
      file: "{{ Ambiente }}.yml"
      name: INFO_AMBIENTE

  - name: "adding string value tipo to list"
    set_fact:
      LIST_BASES: "{{ ITEM.BASE + ITEM.TWO_TASK + [{'TIPO':{% if ITEM.TWO_TASK=='sc' or ITEM.TWO_TASK=='si' %}ITEM.TWO_TASK{% else% }slu }] }}" 
    with_items: "{{ INFO_AMBIENTE.LIST_BASES}}"
```

```yml
#expected result

LIST_BASES: 
  - { BASE: 'ambprueba_sc'    ,TWO_TASK: 'sc'  ,TIPO: 'sc' }
  - { BASE: 'ambprueba_si'    ,TWO_TASK: 'si'  ,TIPO: 'si'}        
  - { BASE: 'ambprueba_slucs' ,TWO_TASK: '001' ,TIPO: 'slu'}
  - { BASE: 'ambprueba_sluod' ,TWO_TASK: '105' ,TIPO: 'slu'}
```

```
#error:
fatal: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected '%'. String: {{ ITEM.BASE + ITEM.TWO_TASK + [{'TIPO':{% if ITEM.TWO_TASK=='sc' or ITEM.TWO_TASK=='si' %}ITEM.TWO_TASK{% else% }slu }] }}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  - set_fact:
      LIST_BASES: []

  - name: "adding string value tipo to list"
    set_fact:
      LIST_BASES: "{{ LIST_BASES + [item | combine({'TIPO': item.TWO_TASK if item.TWO_TASK=='sc' or item.TWO_TASK=='si' else 'slu'})] }}"
    with_items: "{{ INFO_AMBIENTE.LIST_BASES }}"
```

The first `set_fact` task initialises the variable as a list. The second `set_fact` task appends a new list entry, which is the original `dict` combined with a new `dict` for the 'TIPO' key. The value for 'TIPO' is conditionally set based on your requirements.